# How to send a post request and get a pdf files in the web page?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# console application, and I'm using web client to download some files from a web page. the problem is it returns a 404 error when i give the direct download url to download the file using web client. What i want is to open the page with a post request and then initiate the download with urls in that page. I don't understand how to call the page with a post request and through that how to download the file. I'm new to programming, so i hope this way it will work.

This is the page :

this is what i tried so far, and it didn't work.

```
 private void DownloadFile(string fileType, string list)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "http://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/speedSearch.do?affiliateId=97&memberId=MPSNQTVY1CGKAEI&cusip=738855DC6");
            webClient.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/" + list + ".pdf", @"E:\\New\\CUSIPS_" + fileType + "_" + list + ".pdf");
            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded: CUSIPS_" + fileType + "_" + list + ".pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8z1M.jpg)

Comment: `"how to call the page with a post request"` - why POST?  That URL looks like a GET request to me.  Is it a REST API?

Comment: @squillman Can you tell me how to do it then?

Comment: @DinukshiJayarathne is my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Sakura Check ur answer

Comment: Can you post what `Console.WriteLine("Downloaded: CUSIPS_" + fileType + "_" + list + ".pdf");` output?

Comment: I posted a image with the question, please check

Comment: If you can output the file "Downloaded..." then the download is success. Check your hard drive if the file exist.

Comment: no it doesn't exists

Comment: Please post the code that output the "Error" lines also.

Comment: Check  the question now

Comment: The funny thing is if i open these download links on browser and then run the code, it downloads all the pdf's without a problem

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. You need to sent `Referer` header, and it is GET, not POST request.

```
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/speedSearch.do?affiliateId=97&memberId=MPSNQTVY1CGKAEI&cusip=738855HJ7");
    wc.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/k36062.pdf", @"D:\pathToFile");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

for other urls, you have to change Referer address. Example:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/multiThreaded.do?method=DIRECT&fileType=MAVEN&list=k15547");
wc.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/k15547.pdf", @"D:\pathToFile2");
```

And:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/multiThreaded.do?method=DIRECT&fileType=MAVEN&list=i83453");
    wc.DownloadFile("http://munifilings.com/pdfs/0/i83453.pdf", @"D:\pathToFile4.pdf");
```

Comment: > Im sending your code trough a loop to download all the files, it still gives 404

Comment: @DinukshiJayarathne copy/paste whole my code to see if it have error. On my pc it is ok

Comment: try giving these paths without opening them in the browser.

Comment: http://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/multiThreaded.do?method=DIRECT&fileType=MAVEN&list=i83453

Comment: Yes I understand your point, but for some reason when i change the referer and download URL it still gives 404 not found. But if i open that url in browser and run the code it will download as expected. if not it wont. I don't know the reason.

Comment: I need to know if my code work on your computer? If yes, update you question and post your new code, I will try to find other error.